# Skip all lines in try if one line fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

NEW CODE:

If the file is not in the folder. Then I dont want to make new dir.

```
import os
try:
    filename = "test123.pdf"
    folder = "someFolder"
    os.mkdir (folder)
    os.rename(filename,"someFolder\\test123.pdf")
except:
    print "File not found"
```

Comment: Switch lines 3 and 4, of course.

Comment: Please try it before saying that it doesn't work.

Comment: If you mean "sure, that will help for the simple example I've given, but not for my actual code", then please come up with a different example that better reflects your problem.

Comment: The short answer is, you can't. its common to break a problem into _(1) check error conditions, (2) setup for all actions, (3) do actions_  but even then you have a problem if something goes wrong in the "do" stage. If actions are reversable, you can record things as you do them and undo them in the error handler.

Comment: Please don't edit a question and change it completely... that should be done by asking a new question.

Comment: Sorry. But it is the exact same problem.

Comment: No, it's not the same problem. Your original question asked how to execute one line before the other. Your new question asks how to use a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can test before you take action:

```
import os
try:
    filename = "test123.pdf"
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        raise OSError("File not found")
    folder = "someFolder"
    os.mkdir (folder)
    os.rename(filename,"someFolder\\test123.pdf")
except:
    print "File not found"
```

Or, if you want to deal with other issues like not having rights to move the file, unwrap later:

```
import os
try:
    filename = "test123.pdf"
    folder = "someFolder"
    os.mkdir (folder)
    os.rename(filename,"someFolder\\test123.pdf")
except:
    if os.path.isdir(folder):
        os.rmdir(folder)
    print "File not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run line 3 only if line 4 succeeds, then you would be better off to combine each string you want to print together into an array, and then print the results after all of the lines have succeeded:

```
    print "Print ME"
    strings = []
    try:
        strings.append("1)Only print if try go through")
        strings.append(1/0) # this line will fail because of divide by zero
        strings.append("2)Only print if try go through")
        print str.join("\n", strings) # this would only print if above statements succeeded
    except:
        print "Fail"
```

Comment: The above answer was based on the *original* question that was asked, not the edited one regarding creating a new directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want line 3 to run only if line 4 succeeds, then you need to switch line 3 with line 4.

Answer (score 0):

While the prevailing Python style is "ask forgiveness rather than seeking permission", this seems like a good spot to instead employ "look before you leap". Actually check if the file exists before taking any actions.

```
import os

filename = "test123.pdf"
folder = "someFolder"
if os.path.isfile(filename):
    os.mkdir (folder)
    os.rename(filename,"someFolder\\test123.pdf")
else:
    print "file not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is now completely different from its original form, I'm adding a new answer.

Executing a statement based on a condition means you should use an `if` statement.

```
import os
try:
    filename = "test123.pdf"
    folder = "someFolder"
    if filename not in os.listdir(folder): # this line is the key
        os.mkdir (folder)
    os.rename(filename,"someFolder\\test123.pdf")
except:
    print "File not found"
```